# Getting "PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed" error on WEBLOGIC

Tags: java, certificate, weblogic

After applying the latest Windows Updates I'm getting an:

> Error 500--Internal Server Error

trying to access my URL using HTTP (not HTTPS!) protocol.

Looking in Weblogic logs, I found this error:

> ServletContext@199346236[app:analytics module:analytics path:/analytics spec-version:2.5 version:11.1.1]] Root cause of ServletException.
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: **PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed**

How can I solve this issue?

I don't know where I can find this expired certificate and if this is the real problem because I'm not using an HTTPS protocol trying to access my site.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to find the location of your certificates first or your certificates are located in your keystore. If so, you can display content of your keystore and check which certificates you have.

Do you use Weblogic in combination with OSB? If yes, then the keystore is propably configured in your Enterprise Manager. If not, then your keystore is configured on Weblogic level which can be found at servers -> keystores tab

I don't know if this is the solution but let's try it out.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).